# Calculate size of a folder in Azure data lake Gen2 by excluding the blobs in Archive tier

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-databricks

I need to calculate the size of an ADLS folder but need to make sure blobs in the Archive layer are excluded from the list.
If I use

```
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container $containerName -Prefix $folderName
```

Its giving the size but there is no way I can filter out the access tier.
[image]

But If I use BlobServiceClient, the code is not scalable, it runs forever if I have millions of files.

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=storage_account_key)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_path)
for blob in blob_list:
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    if blob_properties.blob_tier != "Archive":
            total_size += blob_properties.size
```

Is there an easy and scalable way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your code is not optimized. You need not call `blob_client.get_blob_properties()` method to get the properties of the blob for each blob. They should already be available when you list the blobs.

Please try the following code:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=storage_account_key)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=folder_path)
for blob in blob_list:
    if blob.blob_tier != "Archive":
            total_size += blob_properties.size
```

Also, looking at the documentation of [`Get-AzStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-11.3.0), the output of the cmdlet would be a list of blobs which are of type [`AzureStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestorageblob?view=az-ps-latest) and that has a property called `AccessTier`. What you can do is loop through the blobs returned by this Cmdlet and filter by access tier to get the desired information.